# Vertically align <p> element

Tags: css, html, alignment

I need to align the `p` element to the bottom center of the page but something is wrong. I am making an HTML5 page.

Here is the CSS selector:

```
p { vertical-align:80px; }
```

Comment: Yes I do have /style there

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle.net example and the rest of the relevant code?

Comment: The questioner is new, at least tell him what the down-vote is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need exactly "align the p element to the bottom center of the page"

```
p {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/acPJy/)

but it's not the best solution for most websites. Suppose, you are trying to make footer with some copyright (or year, or your name). In this case you have to use more complicated html and css, that includes main div, footer div, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

#### CSS

```
html,body{
  marign: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
body:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
}
p{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Please view the [demo](http://codepen.io/airen/pen/evdEp). You will change the `vertical-align` for `p`, lay hime at top or middle.